# Export part of html i.e. table to pdf with styles

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, export

Is it possible to export for example table, or ul tags with all children elements to pdf file? (COULD WE USE ONLY FREE OF CHARGE LIBRARIES?)

For example I have the table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="my-style">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to export this table to pdf with style. I.e. "my-style" has red color.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: sergey - depending on your requirement and whether it's a production grade app, i'd say that the $150-200 spent on a supported product is excellent value for money. if you've ever had to try and fix opensource code and maintain it against patches, you'll know what i mean. don't close your mind off to the commercial offerings, the value vs cost is just too infathomable to balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use PDF Sharp and Migradoc to generate PDF files on the fly.  Migradoc has good layout and page break controls.

It has table layouts that are pretty easy to understand for most developers.

http://www.pdfsharp.net

Comment: Yeah, I think it is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use iTextSharp lib, this has the ability to decorate display text as you like.

Check this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/iTextSharpTutorial.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I think it is the best solution.

Comment: Also I've found the good sample for this exactly for asp.net mvc: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66948/Rendering-PDF-views-in-ASP-MVC-using-iTextSharp.aspx

Comment: iText/iTextSharp are NOT free of charge unless your solution is open source one.

Answer (score 1):

Sergey,

everyone will have their favourite. however, one that I really like and use literally daily, is the http://www.evopdf.com/. allows you to use your existing asp.net views, so really is a no brainer.

Comment: Jim, it is very nice library I think, but it is not free of charge.